# The same whereClause and whereArgs works in query method and does not in update method

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an android app.
When I use SQLiteDatabase.query with a whereClause and whereArgs it returns a cursor with with count 1.
when I use SQLiteDatabase.update with the same whereClause and whereArgs it returns 0 affected row.

```
int rows = 0;
int r = 0;
Cursor c = sqLiteDatabase.query(Linker.TABLE_NAME,null,Linker.COLUMN_NAME_QUESTION_LINK
                        + " = ? AND " + Linker.COLUMN_NAME_ANSWER_LINK + " = ? AND " + Linker.COLUMN_NAME_FIELD_LINK + " IS NULL",
                        new String[] {question,answer},null,null,null);
                r = c.getCount(); // r becomes 1
rows = sqLiteDatabase.update(Linker.TABLE_NAME,contentValues, Linker.COLUMN_NAME_QUESTION_LINK
                        + " = ? AND " + Linker.COLUMN_NAME_ANSWER_LINK + " = ? AND " + Linker.COLUMN_NAME_FIELD_LINK + " IS NULL",
                        new String[] {question,answer}); // row value still 0
```

Please where is the problem? and how can I solve it?

Comment: Worked with, String update = "UPDATE " + Linker.TABLE_NAME + " SET " + Linker.COLUMN_NAME_FIELD_LINK + " = " + "'" + fieldName + "'"
                        + " WHERE " + Linker.COLUMN_NAME_QUESTION_LINK + " = " + "'" + question + "'" + " AND "
                        + Linker.COLUMN_NAME_ANSWER_LINK + " = " + "'" + answer + "'" + " AND "
                        + Linker.COLUMN_NAME_FIELD_LINK + " IS NULL;";
                sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(update); but question is still need an answer!!!

Comment: All threre SQL statements should be identical. Are the two `query`/`update` calls really executed immediately one after the other?

Comment: CL, yes, the code is copied directly from my source code.